# JavaFX 2.0 resizing everything on scene

Tags: element, resize, javafx-2

Hy everyone. I am having this problem with my app: If i let it in standby(not working with it) for more then 4-5 minutes when i hover elements like buttons, tabs, textfields, textareas, labels etc, they get bigger. And from 100% they go 150% in height and width. Anyone know what may cause this and what could be the reason and how i could stop it?

EDIT:

- JavaFX SDK: 2.0 (x64)
- JavaFX Runtime: 2.0 (x64)
- OS: Microsoft Windows 7 (x64)

Thank you!

Comment: In the `start()` method of your application run `System.getProperties().list(System.out)` and add the property values for `javafx.runtime.version`, `java.runtime.version` and `os.name` to the post.  If the javafx.runtime.version is 2.0.x, then upgrade to 2.1 and try it.  If the javafx.runtime.version is 2.1, then upgrade to the 2.2 developer preview and try it.

Comment: It will not mess with my application the sdk and runtime upgrade? Thanks

Comment: 2.1 is a released version, you should be able to try it (uninstall 2.0, install 2.1, try it out and if needed, uninstall 2.1 and reinstall 2.0) without any issue. 2.2 is a developer preview, it should probably leave your system in a consistent state on install or uninstall, but no guarantees there.  I strongly advise using at least 2.1 rather than 2.0 as many bugs were fixed between 2.0 and 2.1.

Comment: I updated to 2.1 and they are not resizing anymore! Thanks for advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a bug in the 2.0 version of JavaFX which was fixed in 2.1+